# Bytes Operation Python

Tags: python, byte, operation

I am trying to solve an bytes operation:

```
0x25 ^ (0xFFFFFFFF << 1) = 0x87654321 * x
```

I am trying to find the value of x that would make this statement true.

Comment: `x = (0x25 ^ (0xFFFFFFFF << 1)) / 0x87654321`???

Comment: @metatoaster `0x25 ^ (0xFFFFFFFF << 1)` is an integer number, and so is 0x87654321. However, they cannot be divided without a remainder. The problem as written does not seem to have a solution.

Comment: Hence I am wondering with ??? because I have no idea why this is so special in Python, given that `*` will work transparently with a float.

Comment: @metatoaster is correct since `0x25 ^ (0xFFFFFFFF << 1) == 0x87654321 * ((0x25 ^ (0xFFFFFFFF << 1)) / 0x87654321)` outputs `True`. There isn't even rounding errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions `0x25 ^ (0xFFFFFFFF << 1)` and `0x87654321` evaluate to nothing but integers, respectively `8589934555` and `2271560481`.

And if you want to solve `8589934555 == 2271560481 * x`, well you just divide.

```
# Reminder: in Python3, / will always output a float
x = (0x25 ^ (0xFFFFFFFF << 1)) / 0x87654321 # Output: 3.781512588746256

0x25 ^ (0xFFFFFFFF << 1) == 0x87654321 * x # Evaluates to True
```

You might have been overthinking this, keep in mind that `0x25`is nothing but hexadecimal *notation* for an integer. It means that, for Python it is exactly the same as writing `37`.

Moreover operations such as `^` and `<<` will return integers as well, so there really is nothing to worry about once you get the value they output. Elementary algebra still applies.